# DNS domain redirection "stacking"?

Tags: http, redirect, dns

I'm trying to manage my current inventory of domains, and I don't want them to just generate a connection error upon request or land on a default page from the registrar.

Is it possible to redirect all domains to a certain domain, then redirect that domain to yet another domain, and be able to handle all redirection requests in a "stack"?

```
Example:

Primary Domain (primary.com)

Landing Domain (landing.net) (redirected to primary.com)

Domain Inventory (all redirected to landing.net)
```

What I'm asking is.. With my entire inventory going to that landing domain, can I just configure that landing domain's redirection to do a second redirect in the request?

```
randominventorydomain.net => landing.net => whatever is specified for landing.net's redirection
```

I guess it would be called a double redirect?

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: So which of these is DNS redirection, and which is HTTP redirection?

Comment: I may have used the wrong terminology. I mean in just HTTP requests in browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both redirections are in fact HTTP 3xx redirections, then the landing.net HTTP server could read the "Referer" HTTP header, and include its value in a URL parameter in the "Location" header of the 3xx response.

Comment: I can't say I'm 100% certain on what you mean, but are you saying that it will in fact deal the original redirect, followed by the second one assigned to the landing?

Comment: I am assuming you have little control over the first redirect. (from foo.com to landing.net.) But you can host a small application on loading.net, that has access to the original URL in the "referer" header of the incoming request, and it can include this information as a parameter in the URL it redirects to: primary.com?originalUrl=foo.com